# jQuery UI autocomplete widget - how to get a reference to the menu?

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to be able to get a reference to the menu object that autocomplete builds, (so I can get the `.attr("id")` for example), but I'm not very familiar with jQuery/javascript. In the source, I found this:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1-9-stable/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L182

so there is an object flying around, I just can't seem to find how to get hold of it.

So, for example, if I've got an input with an autocomplete bound to it like this:

```
// input = reference to the input text box on the form
input.autocomplete({
  select: function(event, ui) {
    // how to get the reference here?

    // some things I've tried
    // return input.menu
    // return input.data("menu")
    // and a few others but they didn't work either
  }
});
```

I tried looking at the data object itself, but there were so many options I could spend all day looking at it and still not find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the widget's reference by looking into dataset assigned to its root element (input). Then fetching menu property (and its underlying element) is kinda trivial. )

```
  select: function(event, ui) {
    // that's how get the menu reference:
    var widget = $(this).data('ui-autocomplete'),
        menu   = widget.menu,
        $ul    = menu.element,
        id     = $ul.attr('id'); // or $ul[0].id
  }
```

... as `this` within `select` function refers to the `<input>` when this function called as an event handler.

Comment: Minor nitpick: From jQuery UI 1.9 onwards, accessing the widget from its non-qualified name is deprecated, and will not be supported in 1.10. It may be best to use the qualified name here: `var widget = $(this).data("ui-autocomplete")`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thank you, didn't know that; will update the answer (and some of my code as well).

Answer (score 5):

A simpler way to do this:
`$(this).autocomplete('widget');`
It does the same as:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
// that's how get the menu reference:
var widget = $(this).data('ui-autocomplete'),
    menu   = widget.menu,
    $ul    = menu.element,
    id     = $ul.attr('id'); // or $ul[0].id
```

}

It gives the ul list

`$(this).autocomplete('widget').attr('id');`